# How to display Select Files field using Low Variables

Tags: low-variables

I have a Low Variable titled lv_accreditations to allow the client to select a series of logos to display in the site footer.

The variable is set to Enable Early Parsing and to output a comma seperated list.

However, i'm unsure how to actually display these in a template so that I can add additional tags around the outputted list. I'm using the following but i'm just not sure what to put in the src attribute and have the li created for image image in the Select Files field.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_accreditations"}
<li><img src="" /></li>
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Grateful for any assistance with this one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Heh, after a bit more sweating here in blighty I managed to figure it out.

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_accreditations" multiple="yes"}
<a href="#"><img src="{lv_accreditations:data}" /></a>
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```